# How to insert a foreign key spring mvc jdbc template

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm doing a crud with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) ,
    nombre varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    precio varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    fecha_vencimiento varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (NOMBRE) REFERENCES FABRICANTE(NOMBRE));
CREATE FABRICANTE (
    nombre varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    direccion varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    telefono varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    tipo varchar(40) NOT NULL);
```

but I have not found how to insert the value of the foreign key in the table productos. 
currently I'm only saving the data from the product table, but not the foreign key
    package Controller;

```
import Modelo.Conectar;
import Modelo.Productos;
import Modelo.ProductosValidar;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
* @author aula3
*/
@Controller
@RequestMapping("add.htm")
public class AddController {
ProductosValidar productosValidar;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public AddController()
{
    this.productosValidar=new ProductosValidar();
    Conectar con=new Conectar();
    this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(con.conectar() );
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView form()
{
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("add");
    mav.addObject("productos",new Productos());
    return mav;
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView form
    (
            @ModelAttribute("productos") Productos p,
            BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status
    )
{
    this.productosValidar.validate(p, result);
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("add");
        mav.addObject("productos",new Productos());
        return mav;
    }else
    {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update
    (
    "insert into productos (nombre,precio,fecha_vencimiento ) values (?,?,?)",
     p.getNombre(),p.getPrecio(),p.getFecha_vencimiento()
    );
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home.htm");
    }

}
}
```

In which part of the controller should I place the code of the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

you have the line `FOREIGN KEY (FABRICANTE_NOMBRE) REFERENCES FABRICANTE(NOMBRE));`
but you don't have a column in your table called `FABRICANTE_NOMBRE`

Comment: I already corrected the foreign key, as I do to add the foreign key in the table productos